# String array not updating properly in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a for loop, which scans through a user inputted string named `text`, subtracts a number (int key) from its ASCII value, and replaces each character in a new string (`textEnc`). There's an issue with how the characters are being passed to the new string array.

Each time the for loop cycles, the current character and all the characters prior are replaced. So if the initial string was to be "TEST", without applying a key subtract, the output would be "TTTT". It replaces all the first character with the second character, then replaces all the second character with the first character.

Why is this happening? And how to solve it?

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   // Interface for inputting and storing string and key

   string text = get_string("String to encrypt: ");
   int length = strlen(text);

   int key = 0;   // User inputs a key between 1 and 15.
   do
   {
      key = get_int("Enter key [1-15]: ");
   } while (key < 1 || key > 15);


   string textEnc[length]; // empty array initialised to store the encrypted string. It is set to the same length as the inputted string.

   for (int i = 0, j = length; i < j; i++)
   {
      char asc = text[i] - key;
      textEnc[i] = &asc;
   }

}
```

I tried moving the contents of one string over to another, character by character, but each "cycle" replaces all characters before it with the current one.

How do I change `textEnc` to a char instead of a string array?

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of *strings* for `textEnc`, and not an array of characters?

Comment: As for the problem you seem to wonder about, a compiler may reuse memory for local variables. For the `for` loop, there will be only one single `asc` variable, and you make all elements of `textEnc` point to this single variable. And once the loop iterates, or ends, the pointer will become invalid as the life-time of `asc` have ended.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, probably not! my reasoning was that it'd be easier to print it as a string, and stupidly didnt look at it as an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Someprogrammerdude. Makes total sense! Changing 'textEnc' to a char actually solved the issue, and that additional information seems invaluable.

Comment: In C, a string is really called a ***null-terminated** string*. For a string to be used as a string, it needs the null-terminator at the end, otherwise all functions you pass it to will not know where it ends. If you use `&asc` as a string, for example `printf("%s\n", &asc)` you will have *undefined behavior*. And as mentioned, once the loop ends the pointer isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and when I compiled the code, I received a warning about attempting to store a pointer value within an character/integer.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/CS_Encrypt/main.c|28|warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
```

At issue, is this line of code.

```
    textEnc[i] = &asc;
```

To better illustrate what is happening here, I added in some "printf" statements to illustrate the process that is happening.

```
   for (int i = 0, j = length; i < j; i++)
   {
      char asc = text[i] - key;
      printf("Text character is: %c  Encrypted character is: %c  Address of encrypted character is: %p: \n", text[i], asc, &asc);
      textEnc[i] = &asc;
      printf("textEnc[i] contains: %c which has an integer value of: %d\n", textEnc[i], textEnc[i]);  /* The address of the encrypted character is getting placed into the character array    */
   }

   printf("Following is the resulting string: %s\n", textEnc);
```

Following is some sample output denoting the undefined behavior of the storage of the memory pointer of variable "asc" in the encrypted text array.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CS_Encrypt/bin/Release$ ./CS_Encrypt 
String to encrpyt: Hello
Enter key [1 - 15]: 2
Text character is: H  Encrypted character is: F  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffc249e766b: 
textEnc[i] contains: k which has an integer value of: 107
Text character is: e  Encrypted character is: c  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffc249e766b: 
textEnc[i] contains: k which has an integer value of: 107
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffc249e766b: 
textEnc[i] contains: k which has an integer value of: 107
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffc249e766b: 
textEnc[i] contains: k which has an integer value of: 107
Text character is: o  Encrypted character is: m  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffc249e766b: 
textEnc[i] contains: k which has an integer value of: 107
Following is the resulting string: kkkkk
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CS_Encrypt/bin/Release$ ./CS_Encrypt 
String to encrpyt: Hello
Enter key [1 - 15]: 2
Text character is: H  Encrypted character is: F  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffdbc272aab: 
textEnc[i] contains: � which has an integer value of: -85
Text character is: e  Encrypted character is: c  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffdbc272aab: 
textEnc[i] contains: � which has an integer value of: -85
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffdbc272aab: 
textEnc[i] contains: � which has an integer value of: -85
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffdbc272aab: 
textEnc[i] contains: � which has an integer value of: -85
Text character is: o  Encrypted character is: m  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffdbc272aab: 
textEnc[i] contains: � which has an integer value of: -85
Following is the resulting string: �����
```

Each element of the encrypted text array is a character and what you would just want to do is store the value that is derived in the "asc" character variable.  Following is the refactored code illustrating that point.

```
       for (int i = 0, j = length; i < j; i++)
   {
      char asc = text[i] - key;
      printf("Text character is: %c  Encrypted character is: %c  Address of encrypted character is: %p: \n", text[i], asc, &asc);
      textEnc[i] = asc;  /* Refactored */
      printf("textEnc[i] contains: %c which has an integer value of: %d\n", textEnc[i], textEnc[i]);  /* The address of the encrypted character is getting placed into the character array    */
   }

   printf("Following is the resulting string: %s\n", textEnc);
```

Retesting this code produces what is most likely the type of output being sought.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CS_Encrypt/bin/Release$ ./CS_Encrypt 
String to encrpyt: Hello
Enter key [1 - 15]: 2
Text character is: H  Encrypted character is: F  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffe24ba3c4b: 
textEnc[i] contains: F which has an integer value of: 70
Text character is: e  Encrypted character is: c  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffe24ba3c4b: 
textEnc[i] contains: c which has an integer value of: 99
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffe24ba3c4b: 
textEnc[i] contains: j which has an integer value of: 106
Text character is: l  Encrypted character is: j  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffe24ba3c4b: 
textEnc[i] contains: j which has an integer value of: 106
Text character is: o  Encrypted character is: m  Address of encrypted character is: 0x7ffe24ba3c4b: 
textEnc[i] contains: m which has an integer value of: 109
Following is the resulting string: Fcjjm
```

The takeaway from this is being cognizant of when one wants to reference values and when one wants to reference pointers to variables.  You might want to delve into some more "C" tutorials on the usage of character arrays, characters, and pointers.